# Send $variable to a view in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have an `$alerts` variable array.

Look like this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "status" => 200
    "message" => "Success"
    "data" => []
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "status" => 200
    "message" => "Success"
    "data" => []
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "status" => 404
    "error_code" => 35
    "message" => "invalid json - api not supported"
  ]
]
```

I want to send it from my controller to my view.

I've tried this

## controller

`return Redirect::to('/account/'.$id)
 ->with('alerts',$alerts)`

## Route

My route : http://localhost:8888/account/1007

## View

I tried accessing like this

`{!!$alerts!!}`

Then, I tried accessing it like this, but I kept getting

> Undefined variable: alerts

Comment: The `->with('varname', $varname)` method means you can access simply through `{{$varname}}` in your view.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No it doesn't. It includes the variable in the next request. It is up to the next request to pass it to the view.

Comment: I thought in Laravel 5. We use {!!$variable!!} to access our variable.

Comment: @jfadich You're right, I'm thinking about when passing it directly to a view using `View::....->with('varname', $varname)`.

Comment: Is the error occurring in the controller, or the view? Maybe `$alerts` isn't defined in your  controller?

Comment: @MaHo I did a check before I send it out. My alerts array exist and containing 3 elements. I'll show you. I'll update my post.

Comment: Could you post the code that is actually returning the view?

Comment: @ihue You should only use `{!! !!}` if you absolutely have to. That will not escape the value for you leaving you open to XSS attacks. You should always use `{{ }}` unless you explicitly intend to display HTML.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thanks for the tips. I always confuse between those 2. :)

Comment: @ihue It's easy to mix up especially since that changed between 4.x and 5.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Laravel documentation on redirects](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects), when redirecting using `with()` it adds the data to the **session**, and not as a view variable. Therefore, you will need to access it like:

```
@foreach (session('alerts') as $alert)
    <p>{{ $alert['message'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Well that suggests to me `$alerts` isn’t an array like you say it is.

Comment: It is an array. `$alerts = array();`

Comment: Well it should work then. Please provide the output of `dd(session('alerts'))` in your view.

Comment: That `dd(session('alerts'))` return **null**

Comment: Then its defined, but has a null value

Comment: This is the best answer imo. The only thing I would adjust is checking to see if `alerts` exist beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code that actually loads the view. When you return a `Redirect->with(...)` all you're doing is passing the variable to the next request. In your controller that serves the `account/{id}` route you need to return `view('viewname', ['alerts' => session('alerts')])`

Comment: `redirect()->with()` flashes the data to the session so you access it from the session as suggested by Martin Bean's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Session::flash('alerts', $alerts);
return route('ROUTENAME', $id);
```

Just change ROUTENAME, in the name of the route (if defined in `routes.php`).

For example:

```
Route::get('account/{id}', ['as' => 'account.show', 'uses' => 'AccountController@show']);
```

In this example, ROUTENAME would be `'account.show'`.

---

In your view you can access it by doing:

```
Session::get('alerts');
```

Info: 
- http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data

`Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method.`

Comment: Can you try a `dd($alerts);` after Session::flash, and before the return? If you still get undefined, then the problem is in your controller. If its not in the controller, try a `dd($alerts);` in your blade.

Comment: Sure. I got list of my array to display. :)

Comment: Is  `$tabName` defined? Or does that also give an error?